# Is it possible to simplify this code which iterates a std map?

Tags: c++11, mfc, stdmap

So I have this definition:

```
using HistoryDataItemList = list<CHistoryDataItem>;
HistoryDataItemList m_listHistoryItems;
```

And this method:

```
bool CHistoryData::HasHistoryForAssignment(ASSIGN_TYPE_E eAssignType)
{
    bool bHasHistoryForAssignment = false;
    auto iter = m_listHistoryItems.begin();

    for (; iter != m_listHistoryItems.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (iter->GetAssignmentType() == eAssignType)
        {
            bHasHistoryForAssignment = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return bHasHistoryForAssignment;
}
```

I know that with languages like C# you can simplify the code a bit but can that also be done with MFC when using the newer C++11? Or is what I have written pretty much as simple as it can be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious improvement is using a C++11 *"range-`for`"* loop:

```
bool CHistoryData::HasHistoryForAssignment(ASSIGN_TYPE_E eAssignType)
{
    bool bHasHistoryForAssignment = false;

    for (auto& item : m_listHistoryItems)
    {
        if(item.GetAssignmentType() == eAssignType)
        {
            bHasHistoryForAssignment = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return bHasHistoryForAssignment;
}
```

But thinking about your code, what you really want is to check if **any** of the items matches a particular predicate. [There's an `<algorithm>` for that!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```
bool CHistoryData::HasHistoryForAssignment(ASSIGN_TYPE_E eAssignType)
{
    return std::any_of(std::begin(m_listHistoryItems),
                       std::end(m_listHistoryItems),
                       [](const CHistoryDataItem& item) 
                       {
                           return item.GetAssignmentType() == eAssignType;
                       });
}
```

Alternatively, using a `for` with no extra state is also easy to read and understand:

```
bool CHistoryData::HasHistoryForAssignment(ASSIGN_TYPE_E eAssignType)
{
    for (auto& item : m_listHistoryItems)
    {
        if(item.GetAssignmentType() == eAssignType)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have gone with item 3 as it looks simpler to read. But thanks for also bringing to my attention `std::any_of`. I will look at my other functions now!